# I am having issues with a basic contact manager that I am creating.

Tags: java

I am having some problems with this bit of code. The first thing I did was obviously created some Arrays, these arrays would hold all the information for each contact, as I am building a basic contact manager. My main method just calls my menu method to start the sequence. At my menu, the user has a choice of what they want to do. Whichever choice they choose will be determined by the number they enter on their keyboard. Which in turn, will activate a different method.

The problems I am having is as follows:

1. After pressing "1" which is to view all contacts, the computer either spits out 100 nulls or 100 repeats of whatever I last inputted in the "2", add contacts.
2. Although yes I do want my menu to repeat itself after an action has taken place, it does it too instantaneously. For example, as soon as all the repeats happen after I push "1" it goes straight back to the main menu, and it is difficult to read everything this way.

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


``public class MainHub {

// global variables that will be needed
static String[] name = new String[100];
static String[] number = new String[100];
static String[] email = new String[100];
static String[] address = new String[100];
static String[] birthday = new String[100];
static String[] nickname = new String[100];
static int x;
public static int counter = 0;
static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

    menu(); // call menu method to start program

}

//Holds all the information for the menu
public static void menu() throws IOException{
    int choice = -1; //start at -1 as to not compete with an index number


    while (choice != 7){ //while loop to get a choice from user

        //telling the user what everything is, simple output message
        System.out.println("\t Main Menu\n");
        System.out.println("Enter the corrosponding number for what you want to do.\n");
        System.out.println("1.View all contacts\n2.Add contact\n3.Edit contact\n4.Delete contact\n5.Save contact list\n6.Load contact list\n7.Exit");

        choice = Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine()).intValue(); //this allows the user input to be read and used to make a choice

        switch(choice){
            case 1: viewAllContacts(); //if user inputs 1, call method to view all the contacts
                    break; //stop the loop
            case 2: addContact(); //if user inputs 2, call method to add a contact
                    break; //stop the loop
            case 3: editContact(); // if user inputs 3, call method to view contacts and choose one to edit
                    break; //stop the loop
            case 4: deleteContact(); // if user inputs 4, call method to view contacts and choose one to delete
                    break; //stop the loop
            case 5: saveContact(); // if user inputs 5, call method to save current contact list into a text file
                    break; //stop the loop
            case 6: loadContact(); // if user inputs 6, call method to load a text file to input contacts into array
                    break; //stop the loop
            case 7: System.out.println("You are exiting"); // if user inputs 7, tell user he is leaving
                    break; //stops the loop
                default: System.out.println("That is not one of the options."); // if user doesn't input one of above numbers, it will tell user not an option
        }
    }
}


//holds information, once called upon the user will be able to see all their contacts
public static void viewAllContacts(){


    while(counter<100){ //while the counter has less than 101 it will print out the full list of contacts

        if(counter>0){ //if counter is greater than 0 print list of contacts

    System.out.println("Full name: " +name[x]);
    System.out.println("Number: " +number[x]);
    System.out.println("E-mail Address: " +email[x]);
    System.out.println("Home Address: " +address[x]);
    System.out.println("Birthday: " +birthday[x]);
    System.out.println("Nickname: " +nickname[x]);
    System.out.println(" "); //space so that way the contact list is a bit prettier 

    counter++;

    }else{
        System.out.println("There are no contacts in your list yet."); //else tell user there is no contacts
    }
}

}

//lets the user add a contact and all the information
public static void addContact() throws IOException{

    //as long as the counter is less than 101 you can add contacts



    if(counter<100){



        System.out.println("Enter Contact's Full Name: "); //allows user to add a name to contact
        name[x] = in.nextLine(); //whatever is typed will be added into name variable

        System.out.println("Enter Contact's Number: "); //allows user to add a number to contact
        number[x] = in.nextLine(); //whatever is typed will be added into number variable

        System.out.println("Enter Contact's E-mail Address: "); //allows user to add an E-mail address to contact
        email[x] = in.nextLine(); //whatever is typed will be added into email variable

        System.out.println("Enter Contact's Home Address: "); //allows user to add a home address to contact 
        address[x] = in.nextLine(); //whatever is typed will be added into address variable

        System.out.println("Enter Contact's Birthday: "); //allows user to add a birthday to contact
        birthday[x] = in.nextLine(); //whatever is typed will be added into birthday variable

        System.out.println("Enter Contact's Nickname: "); //allows user to add a nickname to contact
        nickname[x] = in.nextLine(); //whatever is typed will be added into nickname variable

        counter++; //adds 1 to counter to allow space for next contact in arrays


    }else{
        System.out.println("Sorry, the contact list is full."); //if counter is 101 it will print the contact list is full
    }

    System.out.println("Your contact has been added");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using `x` as the index of the array, but `x` is never being incremented.

As you are incrementing `counter`

try

```
System.out.println("Full name: " +name[counter]);
```

likewise with your adding a `contact`

Sort out your indexes.

Comment: See I thought that too, but either which way I go, whether it be counter or x, I still get the whole "null" all the way through.

Comment: not if you have a variable that holds the max amount of inserted records.

Comment: Also you could test and skip the record if null

Comment: Also, `counter` should get reset to 0 at the end of the read.